# Looking for something that will take an SSRS (.RDL) file and produce a PDF file

Tags: reporting, sql-server

I'm looking for a product or method that allows me to take an SSRS report (.RDL file) and a parameter and produce a PDF file as output without manual steps.

This would be triggered when a user opens a specific web page, and in the back end take the .RDL file and a single parameter and output a PDF file to the server.

Environment is SQL Server, SSRS etc. All Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

[Bold Reports Report Writer](https://www.boldreports.com/report-viewer-sdk/report-writer) can go from RDL file to PDF. This scenario is shown in this [demo](https://demos.boldreports.com/aspnet-core/ReportWriter).

[image: Convert RDL to PDF]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.